# TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined while using react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i am using react-router . i have stored data in data.js which goes like this-

```
export default {
    posts : [{
        _id:'12',
        user_id:'123',
        user: 'user1',
        image:'/images/c1.jpg',
        likes: '24'},{......}]
```

i have linked it like this -`<Link to="/post/:id"></Link>`
and aslo given route path- `<Route path="/post/:id" component={postScreen} />`

but in postScreen.js ,when i am doing -

```
const clickedPost = data.posts.find(x => x._id === props.match.params.id );
return (
        <div>
            
            
            <img src={clickedPost.image} alt="post" ></img>
            
        </div>
```

its giving this error-TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

ALSO-

when i do -`const clickedPost = data.posts.find(x => x._id === '12');`
*it works*

what am i doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you `console.log` your `props.match.params.id`, I bet you'll find it's `:to`. You'll want to change your `<Link />` code to actually have the ID you want, like so:

```
<Link to={`/post/${someId}`}></Link>
```